# GTM Reduce number of tags

Tags: macros, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-layers, universal-analytics

GTM up and running, main UA tag in place along with a ClickListener tag.

To reduce the number of macros, i use dataLayer variable Macros for event category, action, label, value & interaction, so they can be used for many rules and tags.

So i want to collect data from one link/button (Add to Fav), i add a rule to listen for the click using {{event}} equals gtm.click and {{Event Label}} equals Add_to_Fav (the label i push to the DL via onclick.

All good so far, but i need to create another UA tag (Track Type - event) that fires on the rule made previously. And this is my question, using this method seems to create many tags. If i have another 20 links that i want to collect data from, do i need to keep creating tags like this. Surely, this will affect page load speed with many tags firing on all pages.

Hope thats all clear.

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for a way to set the event label dynamically since this is the only part that changes in your link tracking ?

Comment: Hi Eike, is my reasoning correct? Do i have to keep creating tags and rules for each click event?

Comment: No, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to retrieve the link text to use it as an event label you do not need many many event tracking tags, that would be horribly verbose. Instead you can use a custom javascript macro - the cool thing about them being  that you can use existing macros inside your custom function.

If you create a click listener or link click listener this will create a few macros - one of them is {{element}}, which is the DOM element that received a click.

Now you create a macro of the type "custom java script", which must contain an anonymous function with a return value.

The barebones version of a function that retrieves the text of a clicked link would be

```
function() {
var el = {{element}};
return el.innerText;
}
```

(actually  you do not need the variable assigment, you could use {{element}}.innerText directly).

You name the macro e.g. Linktext and use the macro {{Linktext}} in your single event tracking tag where it will dynamically be set to the value of the text of the clicked link (although you might want to check cross browser support for innerText, or maybe use innerHTML instead which serves in you use case probably the same purpose).

Comment: Great Eike, that makes sense and cuts down on the number of tags needed. Once the macro is created (below), do i  need to create a tag that passes the text to GA?                              function() {
return {{element}}.innerText;
}

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, its all setup but nothing is being pass via the new tag in Debug mode. I'm passing {{Linktext}} as the event label and using the custom Javascropt Macro in my previous answer. Any thoughts??

Comment: I tested this so I'm pretty sure it works (however you should maybe un-accept the answer until this works for you). The macro is supposed to go in the event label field with a Analytics event tracking tag (it will not track anything by itself, it's merely there to set the event label dynamically so you don't habe to use many event tracking tags).

Comment: I've found out that i was using the clickListener as opposed to the Link click Listener. After the change, i've almost got it running but i can't see hash tag links showing up in real-time/preview mode events. Also, some events are not providing Event category or action values. I think i will be setting up different tags for internal, outbound and image clicks as per another conversation on this topic https://plus.google.com/104258622890980927916/posts/VY3mdBruzJp